# Can I connect two 27 inch (Thunderbolt-2) mac monitors to a 13" 2016 Macbook Pro with touch bar?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I want to run my laptop screen *and both* 27" Apple displays *at the same time*. Basically achieve this setup: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPoGnm7PZQc but with my hardware.

I'm seeing some conflicting reports about my laptop's ability to run two monitors at the same time. There are also bad reviews for the official adapter: https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter?fnode=16b1c754f291e8a4b528715c470463e53359bb4b85ab8f7a3c17a9ca31404b5b0777165ed94086997d7f2f62a908c8e4917dd4622b9fb13f692c13d5db7714673162075736e96e72357cb968f859f469ceabe10ebc138a172aa06414d935cd6d

Is what I'm trying to do possible? And if it is, assuming I have the laptop and two monitors in my possession and I would be buying some sort of adapter *anyway*, what's my best course of action?

Answer (score 1):

That model of Mac will take *two* 4K or *one* 5K display. And since those monitors are 2560 x 1440 (nowhere near 4K) then yes it should work just fine

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. But you will need a good USB C to Thunderbolt adapter (Adapter made by Apple should work).